# Is it possible to Clone a quote belonging to an account into a separate account?

Tags: quote, clone

We already have the ability to clone a quote, but currently it can only clone the account within the same account in which it already belongs. I.E. Is it possible to clone the quote belonging to AccountA into AccountB?

Comment: by creating a visualforce page and a controller class yes.

Answer (score 2):

Sample controller:

```
public with sharing class QuoteClone {
    public Opportunity opp { get; set; }

    public QuoteClone() {
        opp = new Opportunity();
    }
    public pagereference savedata() {
        PageReference ref = null;
        if(opp.SyncedQuoteId==null) {
            opp.SyncedQuoteId.addError('You must select a quote.');
        }
        if(opp.AccountId==null) {
            opp.AccountId.addError('You must select an account.');
        }
        if(opp.SyncedQuoteId!=null && opp.AccountId != null) {
            Set<String> QuoteFields = schema.Quote.sobjecttype.getdescribe().fields.getmap().keyset(),
                        OppFields = schema.opportunity.sobjecttype.getdescribe().fields.getmap().keyset(),
                        QuoteLineFields = schema.quotelineitem.sobjecttype.getdescribe().fields.getmap().keyset();
            Quote q = (Quote)Database.query('select '+String.join(new list<string>(quotefields),',')+' from quote where id = \''+opp.syncedquoteid+'\'');
            Opportunity o = (Opportunity)Database.query('select '+String.join(new list<string>(oppfields),',')+' from opportunity where id = \''+q.opportunityid+'\'');
            o = o.clone(false,false,false,false);
            q = q.clone(false,false,false,false);
            o.accountid = opp.accountid;
            insert o;
            q.opportunityid = o.id;
            insert q;
            QuoteLineItem[] items = (QuoteLineItem[])Database.query('select '+String.join(new list<string>(quotelinefields),',')+' from quotelineitem where quoteid = \''+opp.syncedquoteid+'\'');
            items = items.deepClone(false,false,false);
            for(QuoteLineItem item:items) {
                item.quoteid = q.id;
            }
            insert items;
            ref = new Apexpages.standardcontroller(q).view();
        }
        return ref;
    }
}
```

Sample page:

```
<apex:page controller="QuoteClone">
    <apex:sectionHeader title="Clone Quote"/>
    <apex:form >
        <apex:pageBlock title="Clone Quote">
            <apex:pageBlockSection columns="1">
                <apex:inputField value="{!Opp.SyncedQuoteId}"/>
                <apex:inputField value="{!Opp.AccountId}"/>
            </apex:pageBlockSection>
            <apex:pageBlockButtons >
                <apex:commandButton value="Save" action="{!saveData}"/>
            </apex:pageBlockButtons>
        </apex:pageBlock>
    </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

Only minimal error checking is involved, as this is only for demonstration purposes, but the code does work (but doesn't clone the opportunity line items or sync with the new opportunity).

Answer (score 0):

Not too hard.  this is very basic and can be improved and tweaked, but this will give you the general idea and a good starting point.

Controller

```
    public class myCloneController{

    public list<Quote> results                  {get;set;}
    public Quote originalQuote                  {get;set;}
    public string searchTerm                    {get;set;}
    public Quote newQuote                       {get;set;}  
    public Account newAccount                   {get;set;}

    public myCloneController(){
        results = new list<Quote>();
        newQuote = new Quote(); 
    }

    public PageReference saveNewQuote(){

        newQuote.field1 = originalQuote.field1;
        newQuote.field2 = originalQuote.field2;
        newQuote.field3 = originalQuote.field3;
        //So on and so forth
        newQuote.AccountId = newAccount.Id;

        insert newQuote;

        return page.SuccessPage

    }

    public PageReference runSearch(){

        String soql = 'SELECT id, Name FROM Quote WHERE Id != null';

        if(searchTerm != '' && searchTerm != null)
            soql = soql +  ' and Name LIKE \'%' + searchTerm +'%\'';

        soql = soql + ' limit 10';
        System.debug(soql);
        results = database.query(soql); 

        return null;
    }

}
```

VF Page

```
<apex:page controller="myCloneController">

    <apex:form >

        <div class="section-header">
            Search
        </div>


        <apex:inputText value="{!searchTerm}"/>

        <apex:commandButton id="btnGo" value="Run Search!" action="{!runSearch}" rerender="resultsPanel"></apex:commandButton> 


            <apex:outputPanel id="resultsPanel" >
                <apex:dataTable value="{!results}" var="q" rendered="{!results.size != 0}">
                    <apex:column headerValue="Name" value="{!q.name}"/>
                    <apex:column headerValue="field1" value="{!q.field1}"/>
                    <apex:column headerValue="field2" value="{!q.field2}"/>
                </apex:dataTable>
            </apex:outputPanel>               


       </apex:form>

</apex:page>
```

Comment: You can't set AccountId on Quote; it's derived from the opportunity's AccountId. So, you actually need to (1) clone opportunity, set to new account, (2) clone quote, assign to new opportunity. *Edit* Actually, if this is no longer true, that'd make my life easier, but last I checked, it was read-only.

Comment: Ahh, I did overlook that fox.  I was more looking at it as a general cloning with apex.  I will try to come up with some code for the scenario

Comment: No problem. You might also mention `<SObject>.clone(false)` as an alternative to copying each individual field. Copying one field at a time is so 2010 ;-)

Comment: agreed, was just trying to throw some sample code together for demo.  Looks like its going to have to be much more of an effort now  :)

Comment: @sfdcfox thanks for the info, It's starting to make sense.. We were looking through the code that clones the quotes and saw no relationship between the quote and the account.

Comment: @Dunc44 Thanks for the sample code!